# Tag merge workflow vs user/question merge workflow

Tags: support, status-completed, moderator-tools, tag-merge-utility

When we merge two users or two questions, the merge workflow goes like this:

1. Find the user to merge into another (let's say, User X). Select the "merge" option.
2. Input master user's ID into a textbox, double-check everything, click "Merge".
3. User X disappears and becomes one with the master.

Tag merges seem to go differently. I might be doing this wrong, but following the mental model above, I typically go to the tag that I want to remove, which doesn't really work:

1) Find the tag you want to merge with another. Select the "merge" option:

[image]

2) The "old" tag name is populated in the "new tag name" field:

[image]

3) Do a double-take, copy the tag from the "new tag name" field into "old tag name", and proceed from there.

This seems counter-intuitive, since when we merge X with Y we usually assume that X will be going away (i.e. user X merged into user Y, post X merged into post Y, etc.). Tags seem to have this backwards.

I think it would be better to have tag merges behave the same way as other merges and conversions. Still... is this a defect or by design?

Comment: Agreed 100%, this was very counter-intuitive for me as well.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea what the expected workflow is here, but I don't think I've ever used this tool without cut-pasting the name from box-to-box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy change, I just checked in a fix that populates it the other way around.